# Adding button that removes object from array inside a table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

Created a form and empty table, trough DOM i should create a new object from class Movie and insert it in empty table with a button to remove it.
Don't know how i would create the button with a function to remove the movies[i] in the table. Sorry I am still learning and don't know how to express my problems.

```
window.onload = function(){

    let frmMovies = document.getElementById("frmMovies");
    let txtTitle = document.getElementById("txtTitle");
    let txtYear = document.getElementById("txtYear");
    let txtGender = document.getElementById("txtGender");

    frmMovies.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        let newMovie = new Movies(txtTitle.value, txtYear.value, txtGender.value);
        movies.push(newMovie);
        refreshTable();
        /*let btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
            movies.splice(x, 1);
            event.preventDefault();

       })*/
        event.preventDefault();
    })


}

function refreshTable() {
    let movieTable = document.getElementById("movieTable");
    let txt = "";
    txt = "<tr><th>TÍTULO</th><th>ANO</th><th>GÉNERO</th><th>!</th></tr>";
    for(let i = 0 ; i < movies.length; i++){
        txt += "<tr>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].title + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].year + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].gender + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + "<button class='btn'>" + "Remove" + "</button>" + "</td>";
        txt += "</tr>";
    }
    movieTable.innerHTML = txt;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `onclick` attribute to your Remove buttons when you build it. Upon clicking on the button, it will call a function passing current button element i.e. `this`.

```
let movies = [];

// etc

function refreshTable() {
    let movieTable = document.getElementById("movieTable");
    let txt = "";
    txt = "<tr><th>TÍTULO</th><th>ANO</th><th>GÉNERO</th><th>!</th></tr>";
    for(let i = 0 ; i < movies.length; i++){
        txt += "<tr>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].title + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].year + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + movies[i].gender + "</td>";
        txt += "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn' onclick='deleteRow(this)'>" + "Remove" + "</button>" + "</td>";
        txt += "</tr>";
    }
    movieTable.innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Create your new function which will delete the current row using [.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild).

```
function deleteRow(button) {
    let row = button.parentElement.parentElement;
    document.getElementById("movieTable").removeChild(row);
}
```

This is untested of course but you could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

[**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) is the most efficient way of using one element to listen for an event for multiple child/descendant elements. Simply find an ancestor (tbody) element that the group of target elements (buttons) have in common.

#### Demo

```js
// Reference the <tbody> by its tagName
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');

// Register the click event on <tbody> calls removeRow when clicked
tbody.addEventListener('click', removeRow, false);

// Pass through the Event Object
function removeRow(event) {
  /* Event Object property Event.target always knows which 
  || element was actually clicked. Use event.target to compare
  || or assert a true/false check in order to target the rest of
  || the DOM in reference to event.target.
  || Find the closest <tr> from event.target
  || `this` is the function owner <tbody> which removes the <tr> 
  */
  if (event.target.className === 'btn') {
    var row = event.target.closest('tr');
    this.removeChild(row);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Reservoir Dogs</td>
      <td>1992</td>
      <td>Male?</td>
      <td><button class='btn'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Usual Suspects</td>
      <td>1995</td>
      <td>Male?</td>
      <td><button class='btn'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Pulp Fiction</td>
      <td>1994</td>
      <td>Male?</td>
      <td><button class='btn'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sin City</td>
      <td>2005</td>
      <td>Male?</td>
      <td><button class='btn'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Old Boy</td>
      <td>2003</td>
      <td>Male?</td>
      <td><button class='btn'>Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Event delegation is appropriate mainly if you're expecting to have huge numbers of rows. Not needing a handler for each row can save some overhead. In practice it isn't always necessary.

Comment: If you deal with dynamically created elements then Event Delegation is a must.

Comment: Would you say that even if, say, you're creating exactly one dynamically-created element with an event handler?

Comment: I would do it for even one if I knew there were plans for expansion, besides what is the con for practicing a paradigm such as Event Delegation? Unless explicitly prevented by using `stopPropagation()`, 
 events will bubble and there will always be an `event.target` and an `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: Fair enough. There isn't really a con. I was just worried that the event model might be a hard to grasp without more basic knowledge of the DOM in place. I feel a more ideal answer might list a couple different approaches and then explain why Event Delegation is best practice.

Comment: I always post [this](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm) particular link because it was written well enough for me to understand quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to this, I would recommend really focusing on understanding the difference between an actual DOM element and the HTML tags that are used to create them.

The DOM is the actual mechanism that determines what is displayed on the page. HTML is just a way of serializing a DOM into text, so you can easily send it over networks to other computers. A web browser parses HTML and recreates the DOM on the client's computer.

The DOM consists of JavaScript objects that you can manipulate *with* Javascript. When you set `movieTable.innerHTML`, what you're doing is telling the browser: to do the following:

1. Parse the assigned string as HTML.
2. Delete all of the children of movieTable.
3. Add the new DOM elements parsed from the assigned string as children of movieTable.

This is wasteful because you're recreating the entire table every time you do it, even though you may only be adding or removing a single element. It also can be frustrating to maintain, since JS does not play well with long string literals. This is one of the reasons why stuff like this is often handled by templating libraries.

I'll keep it simple though, and show you how you can do this with just the  standard DOM methods:

```
let frmMovies = document.getElementById("frmMovies");
let txtTitle = document.getElementById("txtTitle");
let txtYear = document.getElementById("txtYear");
let txtGender = document.getElementById("txtGender");

// You don't need to keep getting this every time.
// Just get it once and reuse the reference.
let movieTable = document.getElementById("movieTable");

frmMovies.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    // You can do this anytime, as long as you do it before your
    // handler returns. I usually do it right away.
    event.preventDefault();

    // First, let's create a new table row.
    let movieRow = document.createElement("tr");

    // Create the title cell.
    let titleCell = document.createElement("td");
    titleCell.innerText = txtTitle.value;

    // Create the year cell.
    let yearCell = document.createElement("td");
    yearCell.innerText = txtYear.value;

    // Create the gender cell.
    let genderCell = document.createElement("td");
    genderCell.innerText = txtGender.value;

    // Create the remove button and a cell to put it in.
    let buttonCell = document.createElement("td");
    let removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.innerText = 'Remove';

    // Attach the click handler for the remove button.
    removeButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        // This handler will form a *closure*, which will store the
        // reference to the movieRow, enabling you remove it by simply
        // calling `remove` on it.
        movieRow.remove();
    });

    // Now, let's put it all together:

    // Add the remove button to its cell.
    buttonCell.appendChild(removeButton);

    // Add the cells to the table row.
    movieRow.appendChild(titleCell);
    movieRow.appendChild(yearCell);
    movieRow.appendChild(genderCell);
    movieRow.appendChild(buttonCell);

    // Add the table row to the table.
    movieTable.appendChild(movieRow)
});
```

MDN has some pretty solid documentation of standard HTML DOM that you'll probably want to check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model